# Let's the room be aerated

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

How would you normally ask someone for opening the doors/windows in a an area (like your home or an office) 
to let the fresh air flows in and fill the area with oxygen-rich air?

How about the satate when you are suffering a bad smell within a place and you're going to evacuate the unpleasent air and replace it with a fresh one?

In both above-mentioned cases we would probabely say:

> - Open the windows please. Let's the room be **aerated**.

But I don't know whether this translation is a natural way to say it. Please let me know about it and the way I have to imply this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression we commonly use is "air out" (two words).

> Open the windows please. Let's air out the room.

or

> Let's open the windows and let the room air out.

FYI, the contraction at the beginning of your second sentence isn't quite right in that context. "Let's" is short for "let us". You don't need the "us". So the sentence, "Let the room be aerated." is correct grammar, but "be aerated" sounds rather technical or formal, and not as idiomatic as "be aired out."

Comment: UK speakers may well say "air" rather than "air out".

Answer (score 2):

Open the windows please, **to let some fresh air in**.